# Dismissing view controller to reveal desired one on the backside

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mvp, uisegmentedcontrol, presentmodalviewcontroller

Suppose i have 3 view controllers. I initiate vc1 in vc0 and then vc2 in vc1. Now i want vc2 to be dismissed and after that only vc0 should be shown behind it. How's that possible? I read something about delegate declaration. But couldn't understand.

I have UISegmentcontrol where i'm displaying a controller from storyboard like - vc0 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier=@"vc0"]; and making it a subview of it [self.view addSubview:vc0.view]; Vc0 is a tableView, which has a detailcontroller to be presented. When i tap on a cell, it shows detailview, but actual segmentcontrol.view is lost when detailview is dismissed.

An example would be awesome.

PS: I'm not using segue for the viewControllers. Instead, i'm using presentModalViewController and dismissModalViewController.

Comment: `vc1` and `vc2` are both presented modally at the same time?

Comment: Did you want to dismiss all the view controllers at once?

Comment: from vc0, vc1 is presented and then vc2 from vc1. I want to go directly to vc0 from vc2. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 5 you need to do

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

As of iOS 6 dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: is deprecated.

You need to call

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ // Do something on completion}] 
//If you want to perform something while going through views or other wise keep completion to nil as shown in below code.
```

or

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

or

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Any idea if i have vc0 as the subview of segementControl view? I want to go down to segmentControl view.

Comment: can you put some of the code, so that I can understand what you have done so far and what you want exactly

Comment: I have UISegmentcontrol where i'm displaying a controller from storyboard like - vc0 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier=@"vc0"]; and making it a subview of it [self.view addSubview:vc0.view];
Vc0 is a tableView, which has a detailcontroller to be presented. When i click on a cell, it shows detailview, but actual view segmentcontrol is lost. I don't want that to be lost when detailview is dismissed.